# UBUNTU login goes in loop

Tags: login, login-screen

My Ubuntu is stuck in a login loop when trying to enter my desktop. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

But when i log in to other user which is not a sudo-user it works fine.
i tried each option mentioned in the post
"Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop".
Also i tried with "gdm" instead of "lightdm" it also gives same problem.

Tried with 'Gnome' also..

Answer (score 0):

As Pilot6 suggested, it might be the same problem as [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

The same problem occurred on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation a while back, which was due to a `.xprofile` file in my home directory which didn't contain a proper login script.

Removing or renaming that file made the login process fall back to it's previous behavior.

To rename the file, go to your console by pressing `CTRL+ALT+F1`, logging in, verifying the file exists with `ls` and executing `mv .xprofile{,.bak}` to actually rename it. Return to your lightdm/gdm login screen by first logging out of your console with `exit` and pressing `CTRL+ALT+F7`.

Note that this is only 1 of many possible causes.

Comment: Thanks . I solved the issue as i followed too many links.